# Parse yaml files in Ansible

Tags: ansible

I have got multiple yaml files on remote machine. I would like to parse those files in order to get information about names for each kind (Deployment, Configmap, Secret) of object, For example:

```
...
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: pr1-dep
...
```

```
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: pr1
...
```

```
....
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: cm-pr1
....
```

Ecpected result:
3 variables:

- deployments = [pr1-dep]
- secrets = [pr1]
- configmaps = [cm-pr1]

I started with:

```
- shell: cat "{{ item.desc }}"
with_items:
  - "{{ templating_register.results }}"
register: objs
```

but i have no idea how to correctly parse `item.stdout` from objs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the files:

```yaml
shell> cat configmap.yaml 
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: cm-pr1
```

```yaml
shell> cat deployment.yaml 
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: pr1-dep
```

```yaml
shell> cat secret.yaml 
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: pr1
```

---

Include the dictionaries from the files into the new variables. For example,

```yaml
    - include_vars:
        file: "{{ item }}"
        name: "objs_{{ item|splitext|first }}"
      register: result
      loop:
        - deployment.yaml
        - configmap.yaml
        - secret.yaml
```

This will create dictionaries *objs_deployment*, *objs_configmap*, and *objs_secret*. There are a couple of options on how to create the variables:

- Declare the below dictionary

```yaml
  objs: "{{ dict(q('vars', *q('varnames', 'objs_'))|
                 json_query('[].[kind, metadata.name]')) }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  objs:
    ConfigMap: cm-pr1
    Deployment: pr1-dep
    Secret: pr1
```

If you want the values to be lists change the query

```yaml
  objs: "{{ dict(q('vars', *q('varnames', 'objs_'))|
                 json_query('[].[kind, [metadata.name]]')) }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  objs:
    ConfigMap: [cm-pr1]
    Deployment: [pr1-dep]
    Secret: [pr1]
```

---

- As a next option, you can either use the dictionaries

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        objs: "{{ objs|d({})|combine({_key: _val}) }}"
      loop: "{{ query('varnames', 'objs_') }}"
      vars:
        _obj: "{{ lookup('vars', item) }}"
        _key: "{{ _obj.kind }}"
        _val: "{{ _obj.metadata.name }}"
```

, or the registered data

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        objs: "{{ dict(_keys|zip(_vals)) }}"
      vars:
        _query1: '[].ansible_facts.*.kind'
        _keys: "{{ result.results|json_query(_query1)|flatten }}"
        _query2: '[].ansible_facts.*.metadata[].name'
        _vals: "{{ result.results|json_query(_query2)|flatten }}"
```

Both options give the same result

```yaml
  objs:
    ConfigMap: cm-pr1
    Deployment: pr1-dep
    Secret: pr1
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: all

  vars:

    names: "{{ q('varnames', 'objs_') }}"
    values: "{{ q('vars', *q('varnames', 'objs_')) }}"
    objs: "{{ dict(q('vars', *q('varnames', 'objs_'))|
                   json_query('[].[kind, metadata.name]')) }}"
    obj2: "{{ dict(q('vars', *q('varnames', 'objs_'))|
                   json_query('[].[kind, [metadata.name]]')) }}"

  tasks:

    - block:

        - include_vars:
            file: "{{ item }}"
            name: "objs_{{ item|splitext|first }}"
          register: result
          loop:
            - deployment.yaml
            - configmap.yaml
            - secret.yaml

        - debug:
            var: names
        - debug:
            var: values
        - debug:
            var: objs
        - debug:
            var: obj2|to_yaml

      run_once: true
```

Answer (score 4):

Ansible has a `from_yaml` filter that takes YAML text as input and outputs an Ansible data structure.  So for example you can write something like this:

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - name: Read objects
      command: "cat {{ item }}"
      register: objs
      loop:
        - deployment.yaml
        - configmap.yaml
        - secret.yaml

    - debug:
        msg:
          - "kind: {{ obj.kind }}"
          - "name: {{ obj.metadata.name }}"
      vars:
        obj: "{{ item.stdout | from_yaml }}"
      loop: "{{ objs.results }}"
      loop_control:
        label: "{{ item.item }}"
```

Given your example files, this playbook would output:

```
PLAY [localhost] ***************************************************************

TASK [Read objects] ************************************************************
changed: [localhost] => (item=deployment.yaml)
changed: [localhost] => (item=configmap.yaml)
changed: [localhost] => (item=secret.yaml)

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=deployment.yaml) => {
    "msg": [
        "kind: Deployment",
        "name: pr1-dep"
    ]
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=configmap.yaml) => {
    "msg": [
        "kind: ConfigMap",
        "name: pr1-cm"
    ]
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=secret.yaml) => {
    "msg": [
        "kind: Secret",
        "name: pr1"
    ]
}

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

---

Creating the variables you've asked for is a little trickier. Here's
one option:

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - name: Read objects
      command: "cat {{ item }}"
      register: objs
      loop:
        - deployment.yaml
        - configmap.yaml
        - secret.yaml

    - name: Create variables
      set_fact:
        names: >-
          {{
            names|combine({
              obj.kind.lower(): [obj.metadata.name]
            }, list_merge='append')
          }}
      vars:
        names: {}
        obj: "{{ item.stdout | from_yaml }}"
      loop: "{{ objs.results }}"
      loop_control:
        label: "{{ item.item }}"

    - debug:
        var: names
```

This creates a single variable named `names` that at the end of the
playbook will contain:

```
{
    "configmap": [
        "pr1-cm"
    ],
    "deployment": [
        "pr1-dep"
    ],
    "secret": [
        "pr1"
    ]
}
```

The key to the above playbook is our use of the [`combine`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#combining-hashes-dictionaries) filter, which can be used to merge dictionaries and, when we add `list_merge='append'`, handles keys that resolve to lists by appending to the existing list, rather than replacing the existing key.

Comment: It's strange.I get error `msg: '''recursive'' is the only valid keyword argument'` even though there is `list_marge` argument in the documentation. I use  Ansible 2.8.16

Comment: I used ansible 2.11.2 for testing this, so perhaps consider upgrading. Vladimir has an answer for you that may be work with your version of Ansible.